# iOS: Crash on transaction With realm SDK

Tags: ios, swift, realm

```
Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x00000003d74249bd
Release Type: User
Realm framework version: 10.5.1
Xcode version: 12.3
iOS/OSX version: 14.3
```

-->
Crash on transaction

Crashed: com.apple.root.background-qos

0 Realm 0x1058abfb8 realm::Allocator::translate_less_critical(realm::Allocator::RefTranslation*, unsigned long) const + 68

1 Realm 0x1057fce30 realm::Array::init_from_ref(unsigned long) + 192

2 Realm 0x105ca356c realm::_impl::GroupFriend::get_history_ref(realm::Allocator&, unsigned long) + 68

3 Realm 0x105c3ba60 bool realm::Transaction::internal_advance_read<(anonymous namespace)::TransactLogValidator>((anonymous namespace)::TransactLogValidator*, realm::VersionID, realm::_impl::History&, bool) + 176

4 Realm 0x105c36400 realm::_impl::transaction::begin(std::__1::shared_ptrrealm::Transaction const&, realm::BindingContext*, realm::_impl::NotifierPackage&) + 416

5 Realm 0x105c2b77c realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator::promote_to_write(realm::Realm&) + 268

6 Realm 0x105ca1570 realm::Realm::begin_transaction() + 404

7 Realm 0x10588ee24 -[RLMRealm beginWriteTransactionWithError:] + 24

8 Inventa 0x10510b0a0 $s7Inventa15RealmDataHelperC33saveDataAA0I0CG_tFyycfU_Tf2i_n + 52

9 Inventa 0x1050c2c98 $sIeg_IeyB_TR + 20

10 libdispatch.dylib 0x19941c24c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32

11 libdispatch.dylib 0x19941ddb0 _dispatch_client_callout + 20

12 libdispatch.dylib 0x19942ea68 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 656

13 libdispatch.dylib 0x19942f120 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 116

14 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x1e52d97d8 _pthread_wqthread + 216

15 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x1e52e076c start_wqthread + 8

```
func Inventa15RealmDataHelperC33saveData(notifications: [Notifications]) {
        
        Inventa23.shared56.realmHelper.removeStaleDistinctNotifications654(notificationsofZone: "ezone")

        var filtered:[Notifications] = []
        for notif in notifications {
            for stId in notif.st_ids {
                notif.stId = stId
                notif.notif_key = "\(notif.ntId)-\(notif.stId))"
                filtered.append(notif)
            }
        }
        let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)
        backgroundQueue.async(execute: {
            do{
                let realm = try Realm()
                realm.beginWrite()
                realm.add(filtered, update: .all)
                try realm.commitWrite()
            }
            catch{
                print(error)
            }
        })
    }




  internal func removeStaleDistinctNotifications654(notificationsofZone: String) {
        let notificationsInDB = realm?.objects(Notifications.self)
        let onlyGeoNotifsInDB = notificationsInDB?.filter({$0.notification_identifier == notificationsofZone})

        if let toBeDeletedGeoNotifs = onlyGeoNotifsInDB?.filter({$0.createdAtTimeStamp < Inventa.shared.insertedTimeStamp}) {
            if toBeDeletedGeoNotifs.count > 0 {
                do {
                    try realm?.write {
                        realm?.delete(toBeDeletedGeoNotifs)
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `realm.beginWrite()` comment this line and try.

Comment: This is a cross post from the Realm forums and I will pose the same question; what is this `notifications` Is that an array of unmanaged realm objects or something else? Please review the following [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update the question with more complete information and we'll take a look!

Comment: @Jay Yes, It is realm object.

Comment: I asked that that was *Is that an array of **unmanaged** realm objects*? Also is this `st_ids` a Realm List? It would help us to help you if the guidelines for posting a question were followed - that would avoid tons of comments asking for clarification about the question.

Comment: @jay Notification Array is an unmanaged realm object array. st_ids is realm List

Comment: I don't think there's enough information to answer. However, you may have a threading issue as part of the code is `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)` but then your Realm helper isn't on that same thread.